# How to retrieve search parameters in non-html5 mode

Tags: angularjs

I need to get at the *search* parameters (those after the `?`) not the *hash* parameters (those after the `#`).  Problem is, `$location.search()` switches between them based on the html5Mode settings, which is not what I want.

Short of parsing the URL myself, is there any way to get Angular to disgorge this information?

Comment: Sounds like you want the [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeParams) service.

Comment: @Mike -- thanks, but $routeParams exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: for me its working: [example](http://jsbin.com/EJeritA/2/edit?html,js,output), is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

In non-HTML5 mode `$location.search()` only retrieve information after `#`, e.g.

For url:

```
http://google.com/dir?query=123#/route?a=456
```

$location.search() is `{a: 456}`

$location.hash() is `""`, because if you define non-HTML5 route, everything after `#` will become part of `$location.path()` thus hash is not picked up anymore.

Comment: The correct answer is of the form "$location.xyz() is `{query: 123}`", for some value of xyz.